# Where to ask about laundry recommendations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have several questions about how to wash clothes to achieve

- Cleanliness
- Not damaging the fabric or colors
- Temperature of water
- How to wash different synthetic materials such as polyurethane
- Minimize odor

Which **Stack Exchange site** do you recommend me?

Comment: Search Lifehacks SE if it fits there.

Answer (score 6):

We do not currently have a site to hosts these subjects, but there is a proposal to create a *new* site which is designed to answer these questions:

> ### [Housework](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94962/housework)
>
> Proposed Q&A site for solving those everyday household tasks that come with domestic living and upkeep.

The proposal is pretty far along in the process, but you may want to jump in and 'commit' to using it to help assure it gets created.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94962/housework